# Collections Mangement of Kindle Paperwhite 3

Tags: kindle, kindle-paperwhite, collections

I got my Kindle Paperwhite 3 yesterday and it's my first kindle.

I found the collections is very usefull(which is similary to tags I guess?). Since kindle is slow, I want to group my hundreds of books in PC.

In **Calibre** I install the "Kindle Collection" plugin, but it can't detect the collection information in my Kindle. Nevertheless, I choose "Edit kindle collections manually", and add some books to a collection called "test". Then I disconnect and restart my kindle, nothing happend, the old collections are still there and the collection "test" is nowhere.

I also tried [KDeasy](http://www.kdeasy.com/), it even failed to detect my KP3.

And [Kindle Collection Manager](http://www.kindlecollectionmanager.com/) does the same behavior as in Calibre.

Is this because that KP3 is too latest and besides the upgrade of hardware, the software is also upgraded? Then how can I manage Kindle collections easily for KP3 now?

Comment: Amazon should probably provide an official way to manage Collections from their My Kindle page.  

In my almost one year usage of Paperwhite, I haven't found a good way of managing them.

Comment: @k4rtik have you tried the two software I have mentioned above? Do they work on older Kindle?

Comment: I had tried the Calibre plugin, but I perhaps didn't understand how I was supposed to make it work and gave up. Haven't tried others. But slowly I have grown used to manage collections from the device itself.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative, which at least gets round "kindle is slow" is to use the Kindle app, on e.g. Android phone or tablet, if you have one, to manage your collections.

The Android app does support the new-style "cloud collections", as used by the PW, Voyage, etc.

The advantage here is that it is much more responsive, both in screen display and touchscreen behaviour and, with a tablet, larger with easier to see covers. It supports a multi-select mode, where you can select many titles at once, to add to a Collection.

That's what I do, anyway: use the Kindle device to read, and the Android app to manage.